# ASP.NET Core Web API calling other Web API using Client Certificate getting 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, x509certificate, dotnet-httpclient, client-certificates

I have been trying to add a client certificate to the HttpClient in a .NET Core 1.1 WebAPI for the past 20 minutes and can not figure out what the issue is. When I debug the program and check to see if the certificate was attached with the handler, I am able to see the certificate. I still receive a 401 though. I know for certain that the certificate is properly installed on the other API as I am able to make calls using it from another program. The other program is using .NET Framework 4.5.2, but I doubt that would be the issue the code is almost identical. The only difference is I need to use HttpClientHandlerfor the .NET Core instead of WebRequestHandler.

.NET Core 1.1

```
string uri = "https://other-api-url.com/something";
try
{
    X509Certificate2 clientCert = GetClientCertificate();
    HttpClientHandler client = new HttpClientHandler();
    requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(requestHandler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(uri)
    };

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return Ok(responseContent);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return BadRequest(ex.Message + uri);
}
```

.NET Framework 4.5.2 Code:

```
string uri = "https://other-api-url.com/something";
try
{
    X509Certificate2 clientCert = GetClientCertificate();
    WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
    requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(requestHandler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(uri)
    };

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return Ok(responseContent);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return BadRequest(ex.Message + uri);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying it works in the 4.5.2 version? Unclear from the question.

Comment: Yes it works in 4.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

It is an older post, but I had the same scenario using certificates.

Make sure the `UseDefaultCredentials` property on the `HttpClientHandler` is set to `true`. Because it is `false` by **default**.

See quote below from the HttpClientHandler class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usedefaultcredentials?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_UseDefaultCredentials

> Set this property to true when requests made by the HttpClientHandler
> object should, if requested by the server, be authenticated using the
> credentials of the currently logged on user. For client applications,
> this is the desired behavior in most scenarios. For middle-tier
> applications, such as ASP.NET applications, instead of using this
> property, you would typically set the Credentials property to the
> credentials of the client on whose behalf the request is made.